# android: incompatible types

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

```
package com.bk.criminalintent;


import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

/**
 * Created by Bk on 2016/2/4.
*/
  public class CrimeListActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {
    protected Fragment createFragment(){
        return new CrimeListFragment();
  }
}
```

I'm a beginner of android.  I just cannot understand why the IDE keeps warning me

"incompatible types: 
required: android.support.v4.app.Fragment
found: com.bk.criminalintent.CrimeListFragment"

while I had imported that "android.support.v4.app.Fragment"

Hoping for answer. Thanks!

Comment: Check in your `CrimeListFragment`, you might have used app.fragment there instead of v4

Comment: Thanks, RRR, it works

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, your `CrimeListFragment` needs to `extend android.support.v4.app.Fragment` or you'll keep getting that error due to incompatible types in the `createFragment()` method - which expects to return `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` but is given a `something.Fragment` or something that may not even be a descendant of Fragment to return.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to accept the answer and comment :)